# Log4Net stops logging following db backup

Tags: log4net

On some nights our site stops logging at the time the db backup happens - in the last week, we've had 5 days with no issues and 2 days where we had to recycle the IIS app pool to get logging going again.  We are logging at DEBUG level.  The last item before it stops is a DEBUG-level log.

Our theory is that it only breaks when a request happens at the time of the db backup.

Any ideas as to the potential cause, or a reliable solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log4net stops logging to the database if there is a connection problem. You can set the [ReConnectOnError](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.ReconnectOnError.html) flag on your appender (make sure that you use a very short connection timeout or else your application may hang).